# Is there a way to request webpack with deno

Tags: node.js, webpack, deno

I am currently trying to request the webpack api within a deno application to make my code cleaner. The problem with that is that I don't know how or if you can request webpack via an URL. But I am aware of the fact that deno is a very new runtime and therefore understand that is has not much of support, yet.

Comment: ` make my code cleaner.` ? do you want to format your code?

Comment: There is NO packing of ANYTHING in deno. Only imports.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to the original question about Deno formatting/build tool.**

There are [built-in tools](https://deno.land/manual/tools) in deno which can be useful to you.

To format the code, use `fmt`:

```
deno fmt
```

[More information](https://deno.land/manual/tools/formatter).

To build the application into a single file, use `bundle`:

```
deno bundle [source] [target]
```

[More information](https://deno.land/manual/tools/bundler).